# Can I set a monospaced font in Thunar (or an alternative)?

Tags: fonts, thunar

I'm manually sorting a whole load of data files at the moment in Thunar (1.6.15), in preparation for running a script over them, so my filename convention has to be spot on, though they were saved manually.

Checking the filenames is made harder by the variable-width characters use in the (detailed) file list view.  Is there a way to set a monospaced font? Ideally I'd use one with very good character differentiation (as I'd get in a terminal, or an editor set up for programming)

Comment: Can't you do that from Thunar's preferences? `Monospace`, for example, should be available. I like `Hack`.

Comment: @DKBose I also use Hack for editing, but there are no font settings at all in Thunar's  preferences or the Thunar section of XFCE's Settings Editor

Comment: I'm very sorry! It's quite surprising. In that case, you'll have to bit the bullet and change fonts **globally** via *Appearances*. Change the proportional font to Hack. That works. I just checked.  Once you've done your work, you can revert.

Comment: You can also do so via `Settings Editor > xsettings` and double-click `FontName` and enter the font you want in place of the existing one in the value box to, say, `Hack 11`.

Comment: @DKBose  at least it works instantly and without restarting anything.  My own further reading suggests a possible approach [via GTK+ and CSS](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/hidden-settings) but I don't have time to experiment with it now

Comment: Another option is to use a terminal-based file manager such as `ranger`. There are several YouTube videos on `ranger`. Here's [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMfI415RNEs).

Comment: @DKBose that's interesting, but this morning's sorting operation relied on drag&drop between windows with multi-selected files (ideally not using the clipboard because I was using that to add metadata into the new filename).  While `dragon ` would give me a source I don't think I can drop files into a ranger window, so I suppose I'd be back on dragging into thunar.  I ended up checking the filenames in a terminal window just using `ls`.  This is all because I'm working with completely different tools at home to in work.  It's actually better but the datafiles assumed the work analysis ystem